# If a sequence of polynomials converges uniformly to a continuous function on the real line, then this function is a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

I'm trying to prove that if $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous function and there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is a polynomial itself.

It smells like somewhat near the Weierstrass approximation with polynomials, but I have no idea how to use uniform convergence on the entire real line, since this statement is wrong on any bounded interval.

Any hint or solution will be appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with non-constant polynomials diverging off to infinity. If two polynomials have a different degree, then their distance (which I’d define here as the sup over $x \in\mathbb{R}$ of the distance at $x$) must be infinite.